# Create receipt with escpos package and Serial port

Tags: electron, serial-port, thermal-printer, receipt, escpos

I'm trying build an electron app and create a simple receipt to print via Serial Port.

I'm using:

- electron: `^11.1.1`
- escpos: `^3.0.0-alpha.6`
- escpos-serialport: `^3.0.0-alpha.4`

This is my code to create receipt:

```js
const escpos = require('escpos');
escpos.SerialPort = require('escpos-serialport');

module.exports = {

  printSerial: function(port, data){

    let device = new escpos.SerialPort('COM2', { baudRate: 19200 });
    let printer = new escpos.Printer(device);

    device.open(function(err){
      printer
      .size(1, 1)
      .font('A')
      .encode('CP949')
      .align('CT')
      .style('NORMAL')
      .println('Receipt')
      .newLine()
      .align('LT')
      .style('NORMAL')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: 'Date:', width: 0.2 },
        { text: '2021-01-04 11:11', width: 0.6 }
      ])
      .style('NORMAL')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: 'Order ID:', width: 0.2 },
        { text: '050-7866-2406', width: 0.6 }
      ])
      .style('NORMAL')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '전화번호:', width: 0.2 },
        { text: '200000000', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' }
      ], { encoding: 'EUC-KR' })
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '메모:', width: 0.4 },
        { text: '문앞에 두고 벨을 눌러주세요', width: 0.6 }
      ], 'CP949')
      .drawLine()
      .newLine()
      .println('기사님 이름:', 'CP949')
      .println('기사님 번호:', 'CP949')
      .drawLine()
      .newLine()
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '내부규', width: 0.33, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '내부', width: 0.33, align: 'CENTER' },
        { text: '율과', width: 0.33, align: 'CENTER' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '내부규율과', width: 0.33, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '1', width: 0.33, align: 'CENTER' },
        { text: '2,000,000 원', width: 0.33, align: 'CENTER' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .drawLine()
      .newLine()
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '합계', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '2,000,000 원', width: 0.4, align: 'RIGHT' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '배송료(11.2km)', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '2,000 원', width: 0.4, align: 'RIGHT' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '수수료', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '-0 원', width: 0.4, align: 'RIGHT' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .drawLine()
      .newLine()
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '총금액', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '2,000,000 원', width: 0.4, align: 'RIGHT' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .newLine()
      .newLine()
      .newLine()
      .cut();

      setTimeout(function(){
        printer.close();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

};
```

When I call `printSerial` method. Receipt print success. But text of Korean is incorrect. I was trying with many encoding names but it still not work.

And how can I change font size in receipt, current text on receipt very big.

Maybe I missing something?

Thank advance so much for help.

Comment: It seems that the commentary page says `EUC-KR` instead of `CP949`. Have you tried it? [encode("encodeType")](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos#encodeencodetype), [node-escpos/examples/encode.js](https://github.com/song940/node-escpos/blob/584bdb914c58963233977ea426f6b7e193138c71/examples/encode.js) Alternatively, investigate Issues on the project's GitHub, or ask yourself.

Comment: @kunif : In my code, I use 2 encoding names (`EUC-KR` and `CP949`) to test

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't look at the whole source code. If so, the printer mechanism you are using may be a unique method that is not supported by the library.

Comment: @kunif : yes, I think so

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and I found it and solved it.
I share korean encoding code.

korean encoding code :
`cp949`

and `println` to `text`
this package is too big font size default,
so you need font size control to this

```js
.size(0.01, 0.01) // default .size(1,1)
```

Add This Code :

```js
const options = { encoding: 'cp949' }
```

Full Code :

```js
const escpos = require('escpos');
escpos.SerialPort = require('escpos-serialport');

module.exports = {

  printSerial: function(port, data){

    let device = new escpos.SerialPort('COM2', { baudRate: 19200 });
    const options = { encoding: 'cp949' } // <- Add This option.
    let printer = new escpos.Printer(device, options);

    device.open(function(err){
      printer
      .size(0.01, 0.01) // <-- Font size small
      .font('A')
      .encode('CP949')
      .align('CT')
      .style('NORMAL')
      .text('Receipt') // <- `println` to `text`
      .newLine()
      .align('LT')
      .style('NORMAL')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: 'Date:', width: 0.2 },
        { text: '2021-01-04 11:11', width: 0.6 }
      ])
      .style('NORMAL')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: 'Order ID:', width: 0.2 },
        { text: '050-7866-2406', width: 0.6 }
      ])
      .style('NORMAL')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '전화번호:', width: 0.2 },
        { text: '200000000', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' }
      ], { encoding: 'EUC-KR' })
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '메모:', width: 0.4 },
        { text: '문앞에 두고 벨을 눌러주세요', width: 0.6 }
      ], 'CP949')
      .drawLine()
      .newLine()
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '기사님 이름:', width: 0.4 },
        { text: '기사이름', width: 0.6 }
       ], 'CP949')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '기사님 번호:', width: 0.4 },
        { text: '010-1234-5678', width: 0.6 }
       ], 'CP949')
      .drawLine()
      .newLine()
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '내부규', width: 0.33, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '내부', width: 0.33, align: 'CENTER' },
        { text: '율과', width: 0.33, align: 'CENTER' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '내부규율과', width: 0.33, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '1', width: 0.33, align: 'CENTER' },
        { text: '2,000,000 원', width: 0.33, align: 'CENTER' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .drawLine()
      .newLine()
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '합계', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '2,000,000 원', width: 0.4, align: 'RIGHT' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '배송료(11.2km)', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '2,000 원', width: 0.4, align: 'RIGHT' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '수수료', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '-0 원', width: 0.4, align: 'RIGHT' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .drawLine()
      .newLine()
      .tableCustom([
        { text: '총금액', width: 0.6, align: 'LEFT' },
        { text: '2,000,000 원', width: 0.4, align: 'RIGHT' }
      ], 'CP949')
      .newLine()
      .newLine()
      .newLine()
      .cut();

      setTimeout(function(){
        printer.close();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

};
```

I hope it helps you.